# Notification null when app closed

Tags: java, android

I have problem with my program. I set: .setContentText(powiadomienie). It is working, but only when app is open. When I close app it show null notification. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks and have a nice day!

---

```
nazwaLeku = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

---

```
    dodaj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            NotificationReceiver.xd(nazwaLeku.getText().toString());

            if (nazwaLeku.getText().length() > 0 && ileDni.getText().length() > 0) {

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(year, month-1, day, hour, minutes, 0);

                Intent intx = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intx, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

            }
        }
    });
```

---

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    static String powiadomienie;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent repeating_intent = new Intent(context, RepeatingActivity.class);
        repeating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, repeating_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.kuba.dsadsax/" + R.raw.audio);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setContentTitle("Weź pigułke")
                .setContentText(powiadomienie)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationManager.notify(100, builder.build());


    }

    public static void xd(String lek) {
        powiadomienie = lek;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you called Static Function To Set Value !!!!

that`s your problem

if you want to pass Parameter  You Should Pass It In Intent

Like this

```
  dodaj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            if (nazwaLeku.getText().length() > 0 && ileDni.getText().length() > 0) {

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(year, month-1, day, hour, minutes, 0);

                Intent intx = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
                intx.PutExtra("Value",YOUR_VALUE_HERE_TO_PASS)

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intx, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

            }
        }
    });
```

and then in your BroadCast You can get it From Intent

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    static String powiadomienie;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             powiadomienie = intent.getStringExtra("Value");
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent repeating_intent = new Intent(context, RepeatingActivity.class);
        repeating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, repeating_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.kuba.dsadsax/" + R.raw.audio);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setContentTitle("Weź pigułke")
                .setContentText(powiadomienie)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationManager.notify(100, builder.build());


    }


}
```